# Do Esri developer certifications expire?

Tags: certification, esri-company

Does the `Esri Web Application Developer` certification expire after some period of time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Certifications don't expire, but they are developed for a certain version of the software. And since the software evolves, a certification passed for a certain version may not be really meaningful anymore after a time. Esri doesn't develop certifications for every new version but rather when they judge that the changes between versions are significant enough for the certification to be revised. And for a given version, a review of the certification  might be relevant for a certain product/certification type, but not for the other.

**----- Update - 11 March 2018 -----**

See the [Esri Certificate Verification page](https://www.certmetrics.com/esri/public/verification.aspx) for reference:

> As the technical certification program continues to grow, changes and
>   improvements are made to ensure Esri offers the best possible
>   Certification Exams to the global ArcGIS community. **An exam will be
>   updated only if more than 10 percent of its content is impacted by
>   software version changes.** Exams that are minimally impacted (less
>   than 10 percent) will not be updated for the new software version. If
>   we decide not to update a particular exam, it means that exam applies
>   to the latest release of the software. [...]
>
> Esri certification exams are retired in accordance with the Esri
>   Product Life Cycle Support Policy for mature support. **Exam
>   retirement does not affect any certifications that have been issued
>   for that version. All existing certifications will remain active.**

Esri plans to re-think its certification system so that it's calendar-based and not version-based anymore. As per today, the change is not yet visible in the available exams.

See this blog post - [The Future of Exam Development](https://community.esri.com/community/esri-technical-certification/blog/2018/01/25/the-future-of-exam-development) for details.